# How would you detect a collision in this 2d game below, using javascript and jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, collision-detection, collision

I made a simple game which allows you to move a purple box by pressing the arrow keys. The purple box is inside a blue perimeter. I want to be able to prevent the purple box from being able to breach the blue perimeter and stay inside, which i know involves collisions, however I don't seem to understand how that can be done. Here is the code I have written so far:

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
          <html>
        <head>
       <style>
       body
       {
       background-color:pink;
      }
       #bob
        {
      width:400px;
     height:500px;
       padding:10px;
     border:5px solid blue;
      margin:0px;
      }
        </style>
        </head>
        <body>


        <div id="bob">
      <div id="k"  style="background- color:purple;width:40px;height:40px;position:absolute" onkeydown="keydownControl(this)"/>
     </div>

      <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.0.js">
      </script>
        <script>
    $('html').keyup(function(e){
       if(e.which==37)
     {
   $("#k").animate({left:"-=10px"},1);
    }
   if(e.which==39)
  {
     $("#k").animate({left:"+=10px"},1);
     }
    if(e.which==40)
    {
       $("#k").animate({top:"+=10px"},1);
    }
    if(e.which==38)
      {
   $("#k").animate({top:"-=10px"},1);
       }
       });
   </script>

       </body>
         </html>
```

So lets say I am moving the purple box and it happens to touch the blue square. If that happens if has to stop moving in that direction, until it is no longer in contact with the blue square, thus preventing it from escaping the blue square. How would I do this, using JS and jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hit detection is fairly straight forward, when working with boxes. It sounds like what you're attempting to do is contain 1 movable box (#k) within a static containing box (#bob).

The basic concept is to add some simple logic checks to each of your key up events that check if the position you're thinking of moving to is going to exit the bounds. If the check determines that the new position will exit the bounds, it doesn't bother animating.

Each direction will have a slightly different check.

**UP**

When attempting to move up all you have to do is check that the moving box's new top bound is *greater than* 0. *You can use `jQuery('#k').position().top` to determine the movable box's top bound.*

**Down**

When attempting to move down all you have to do is check that the moving box's new bottom bound is *less than* the containing box's height. *You can use `jQuery('#k').position().top+jQuery('#k').height()` to determine the movable box's bottom bound. And `jQuery('#bob').height()` to determine the containing box's height.*

**Left**

When attempting to move left all you have to do is check that the moving box's new left bound is *greater than* 0. *You can use `jQuery('#k').position().left` to determine the movable box's left bound.*

**Right**

When attempting to move right all you have to do is check that the moving box's new right bound is *less than* the containing box's width. *You can use `jQuery('#k').position().left+jQuery('#k').width()` to determine the movable box's right bound. And `jQuery('#bob').width()` to determine the containing box's width.*

---

**Additional notes**

1. You should probably make #bob `position:relative`. At the moment position will be calculated relative to the body tag's position not #bob's (they just happen to share the same coordinates right now).
2. The reason there is extra logic on "down" and "right" is that position in the DOM is determined based on the top left corner. To compensate for this we must add in the height or width of the object respectively.

---

**Background Information - HTML/jQuery Positioning**

A diagram to help illustrate HTML/jQuery positioning: 
https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/121mfxpapfmcRD2UV7qoMY5RdoH-4womiheqDHtQ_YWY/edit

Each element's coordinate originates from its top left corner.

In HTML/jQuery the position of an absolutely positioned element is relative to its parent's origin *(overlooking position inheritance for simplicity sake at the moment)*. If its top left corner is the same as its parent's top left corner its position will be (0,0). As it moves away from it's parent's top left corner it's coordinates become the horizontal (x) and vertical (y) gap between the 2 coordinates.

Comment: Thanks as well Matt, your methods seem to work. If possible, can you please explain to me how your method works. For example i don't understand why you need to check if the up bound is greater than 0. And where did you even get the 0 from?

Comment: Is it possible for me to change the parent origin of a div element, cos i want to make  a maze for the box by joining various div elements but if you have that whole parent hierarchy thing, it would get too complicated. Or would i then have to use something like canvas, to prevent that??

Comment: It sounds like you may be looking to do something a bit more complicated than just keeping a box contained within another box. At a high level what you're looking to do is insure that a variety of divs within a containing div never share the same space. If the only div that moves is your "player" you can run some logic checks similar to those described above (except now you want to prevent overlap rather than insure it). While none of this requires canvas, the more complicated the maze the more likely it is that you'll want to consider canvas or another medium to address performance issues.

Comment: If you're just looking to do a basic maze, you may not need real collision detection. A linear maze can probably use a simple tile approach. Check out the code found here: http://jsfiddle.net/UDJL6/ . You'll have to pardon the crudeness of the code (I adapted something I'd done for a previous project). This code simply converts a string to a 2d array based on predefined dimensions. 0 is a wall. 1 is a path. And 2 is the player's starting point (also a path). This approach doesn't require pixel by pixel collision detection and may provide much better performance (assuming it meets your needs).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look into the jquery animate's `step` function. You have to check if the object has reached the edge at each step of the animation. Something very similar is done [here](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1856-Using-jQuery-s-Animate-Step-Callback-Function-To-Create-Custom-Animations.htm)

See the "try it for yourself..." link at the bottom.

Comment: Thanks very informative, and for once actually showed me what i was after